# What is wrong with an office file if it displays the windows logo instead of it's usual icon?

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-excel

I was sent a file that I was told should be an Excel file, but instead of the Excel logo, it is displaying the Windows logo. Is this file dangerous or corrupt? Can I fix it or should I just have it sent to me again?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot illustrating the problem.

Comment: Which extension does the file have?  Do you have Excel installed on your machine?  If you try and open it in Excel, what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be several reasons for this:

1. It's not an Excel file.
2. You do not have Excel installed
3. You've been sent an `.xlsx` file, which isn't compatible with your version of Excel. Check the [Filename extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension) of the file. If this is the case, ask the sender to save the file as `.xls` and resend it.
4. Your file associations in Excel are messed up. You can fix this using [this method](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2464297):

   - Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
   - Type appwiz.cpl and then click OK.
   - Select the Microsoft Office suite you want to repair and then click Change.

Comment: The fourth option was what was wrong thank you Kristian

Comment: Please consider upvoting and/or marking the answer as accepted if it was helpful to you.